# How to plot dunn index in r

Tags: r, k-means

I want to make a plot to choose the optimal number of cluster based on dunn index, using kmeans with k from 1 to 10. Please help me how to do that. 
Here is the example result that i want.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWugd.png)

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I dont know to make the plot. I just now that to get the dunn index from the kmeans result is using cluster_stats(dist(data), kmeans.result$cluster) and then km_stats$dunn